# What to use for code being modified at runtime?

Tags: python

Consider two files, `script1.py` and `script2.py`. `script1.py` is a long-running process that listens for messages from an external prompt or connector, and upon receipt of a message it runs the code in `script2.py` to process the message. The user wants to be able to modify the code of `script2.py` while `script1.py` is running, without having to terminate it or restart it, so there's no downtime.

`script2.py` also has some initialisation routines that need to be run ASAP after it's been modified, not wait until the next message comes along for it to be re-run, so there would probably have a process to monitor for changes to `script2.py` and run the initialisation routines when it's been modified.

I've considered 2 options:

- encapsulate the code in `script2.py` into a function and `import script2` in `script1.py`, run the function from it whenever a new message is received, then whenever `script2.py` is modified use `importlib.reload(script2)` to 're-import' it
- `code = compile(open('script2.py').read())` and `exec(code)` whenever a new message is received, then whenever `script2.py` is updated, re-`compile` it and assign to `code`, and re-`exec` with the initialisation arguments.

What are the benefits and drawbacks of each option? Any gotchas to be aware of? How does the performance among other things of each compare? Are there any better alternatives to these two (third-party libraries welcome)?

Considerations:

- `script2.py` has some variables that are needed between runs (of `script2.py`), and `script1.py` has hardly any variables of its own, so with `exec` the variables of `script2.py` should be preserved in the scope of `script1.py` whereas with `import` and `reload` the variables would presumably be stored in a dictionary returned by the function and then passed back to it as an argument on the next run.
- `script2.py` itself imports some standard and third-party libraries. None of the objects based on them are processed in `script1.py` (but may still be among the variables stored between runs).

Answer (score 0):

**method 1:** 'Importlib.reload'
one of the benefits are it is easy to maintain as its aligns with python pratices, it is also easier to handle and catch errors.
The setback is there is any stateful data in 'script2.py', it will be reset with every reload unless it is handled correctly.

**method 2**: 'exec with 'compile'
It is simple to maintain variables from 'script2.py' inside the 'script1.py scope' but If not adequately sandboxed, 'exec' can be a security risk, particularly when dealing with dynamically changing code.

the gothas to be aware of is , It can become difficult to keep track of what is in your namespace, which might result in challenging problems to debug. Dependencies on script2.py will not be automatically reloaded if they change.

when comparing the performance between the two methods the main concern is maintainability and saftey